# jquery Timepicker not working after two or more button click

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I am using https://timepicker.co/ in one of my projects.

The requirement is to trigger the timepicker on the click of a button. I finally got it working by using the following code where `#time` is an `input` element:

```
$("#time").focus();
```

The link to the fiddle is: https://jsfiddle.net/6g2c35hw/2/

Everything is working fine except, when I click the button it opens the timepicker and works fine but if I click anywhere outside (timepicker disappears) and click the button again, the timepicker opens but when I select a time, it doesn't update. You can see this in the jsfiddle. In my project when I do the same, even when I click on the scrollbar or the up and arrows to scroll, the timepicker disappears.

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: it seems it is a known issue: https://github.com/wvega/timepicker/issues/90 Trying to come up with a solution

Comment: looking at the library code it seems that it is both not maintained and incomplete. Lots of todo's that date back more than 4 years according to github. I think you should just go with a different library for this.

Comment: @cornel.raiu I agree with you mate and I wanted to do the same. To explain this in the easiest way, I am not allowed to change the library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `open` method

> `$('#time').timepicker('open')`

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/kbgah0my/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. If you don't mind can you please tell me as to where you found this? I couldn't see this anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: it's in the library code: https://github.com/wvega/timepicker/blob/master/jquery.timepicker.js. This is what it actually does when you 'focus' it ( if you look at line 268 ). Then you can look at lines 207-223 to find the functions it exposes for being called using the method in this answer which also includes the `open` method. I still suggest you should do your best to change the library. But this definitely works.